# Steam OpenID remember me / stay logged in

Tags: php, openid, steam-web-api

I'm making a web app that allows users to login using their Steam account. Here's what I'm using to enable Steam login on the site: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication.

So far it works great. You're able to login with Steam, but I'd like my site to be able to keep them logged in when they come back to  the site. I have looked around a little bit for this but so far I haven't found anything too helpful, or that I would know how to do.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: at this point your question is to broad. please add some code and show what you tried or errors you got while trying

Answer (score -1):

The script you linked use sessions to keep the user logged. Since the sessions ends when the user close the browser, if you want to implement a "remember me" feature you have to modify that script to use something different than sessions (ie: cookies)

Comment: Would that be difficult to do? And more importantly would that be secure?

Comment: Not very difficult. How secure it will be depends on how you implement it, of course.

Comment: How do you suggest I implement it? Like store a key as a cookie that corresponds to a Steam account? I've never really had to do anything like this before so I'd love some suggestions :)